# Atributo skinSimple do Primefaces 5.0 não aparece

Tags: primefaces

Estou tentando usar o componente fileUpload do primefaces e para o que quero, não está aparecendo o atributo "skinSimple", como vi demonstrando no showcase. Até tento colocar o atributo sem o autocompletar mas quando termino de digitar a IDE retorna um erro dizendo que o atributo não existe para o componente.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Você precisa colocar o seu código para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Assim, tento colocar o componente dessa forma: <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/> mas o último  atributo (skinSimple="true") não aparece no autocompletar (Ctrl + espaço) e se eu coloco manualmente, o Netbeans diz que não existe esse atributo para o componente fileUpload. Estou usando Netbeans 8 e Primefaces 5.0 via Maven.